Out of phase comments
The following scenario lead to an inconsistent state in a page:

A answers question Q;
B comments on the answer;
A edits its answer to Q';
B's comment does not apply to Q' anymore.

However, even if B wants to update/remove her comment, it does not work as it seems that comments cannot be edited/deleted after some time has passed.
This leaves a reader confused.

Comments are not "first class" citizens of the site – these are the questions and answers. Everything should still make sense when all the comments are removed, so please put all relevant information in the question (if it could be considered part of the question) or in an answer (if it belongs there). Both types of posts have an edit button, available for anyone.
You should normally be able to delete your own comments – if not, check if you are actually logged in.
Editing is limited to some short time period (except for moderators).
If you come around some comments which are obsolete, please flag them as such. We'll normally delete them (or in rare cases edit them).
Sometimes I go through old questions and delete lots of old and now irrelevant comment threads, even without such flags.

You can flag a comment. Then a moderator will see your flag and can delete it.

For some reason, I could not delete my own comments. It seems to work again.
